# Finding Euclidean distance between two factor columns in R

Tags: r

I was just wondering how could Euclidean distance be found out between two factor columns in R?
For example I have two data frames with two one column each.

```
Dataframe X-      Dataframe Y-
A                     A
C                     B
D                     D
B                     E
E                     C
```

Both data frames have single column with 5 factor levels each:- A B C D E

How can we find Euclidean distance of these two data frames?

One way would be to create dummy variables and go about the simple euclidean distance finding route, but what if factors have different weight-age? Like for example factor A has more precedence over B?
What would be the way to do it in R?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can find it however you want to define it. How do you want to tell if different weightings are better or worse?

Comment: Maybe you should do a little reading about [clustering mixed/categorical data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/24540/7515).